# What does only "git pull" do in a certrain branch?

Tags: git, git-pull

I have a branchA and branchB (main branch). After some code review, I tried to run this first in branchA to pull changes from branchB

```
git pull --rebase origin branchB
```

followed by

```
git push origin -u branchA
```

but I get this error

```
! [rejected](fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to '<url>'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Also i see this on command prompt
[image]

After that, I did just "git pull" (without any arguments) and it works just fine. What happens in running "git pull"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Note: this answer simplifies. But not by much!)

Consider this situation, looking at two versions of the same branch:

```
A - B - C - X (remote)

A - B - C - Y (local)
```

How can these be reconciled? Only one way: by *merging*. If we merge the remote version into the local version, we get this:

```
          -- X --
         /       \
A - B - C         M (local)
         \       /
          -- Y --
```

...where M is a newly created *merge commit* that combines the contributions from X and Y.

Well, that is what `git pull` does. It copies the remote version of the branch down to you, and merges it with your local version.

But it is *illegal* to do that same thing on the *remote* — by saying `git push`. You are not permitted to form a merge commit in that way. The reconciliation can only be performed on *your* computer, locally. You cannot, therefore, push when the remote has commits on this branch that you do *not* have.

Hence when you attempt to do it, the remote Git refuses. The solution of `pull`-then-`push` solves the problem. After you pull, you have all the commits that the remote has, and so the push becomes legal.

---

**Extra information:**

Consider the situation after the pull but before the push. Remember, the remote still has:

```
A - B - C - X (remote)
```

And you now have:

```
          -- X --
         /       \
A - B - C         M (local)
         \       /
          -- Y --
```

When you push, the remote is able to accept these commits *just by adding M to the end of its version of the branch*, like this:

```
A - B - C - X - M (remote)
         \     /
          - Y -
```

It's true that it must also accommodate Y, but the point is that *no new merge commit is needed* in order to do that. This is called a *fast-forward* — no new commits are created, but existing pushed commits are just appended to the branch.

So the rule, technically, is that you cannot push unless it is possible to fast-forward on the remote. When we started, that was *not* possible: somebody must create a true merge commit in order to reconcile these branches, and that somebody is *not* going to be the remote. By doing a pull first, and allow the non-fast-forward merge to happen on the local, you make it possible to fast-forward on the remote.

Comment: Great! that explains it so well. Just had one more follow up question. I sent a PR for branchA against branchB. In the github web interface, I clicked update branch (which probably caused this). however i also ran "git pull --rebase origin branchB" locally while on branchA. Shoudn't they be in sync now? Not sure if I explained it well.

Comment: I'm delighted to talk about that, but not as part of _this_ question. :) It's another matter.

Comment: Sure Sure. thank you again for the beautiful explanation!

Comment: By the way this makes no sense to me: “branchA that is tracking branchB and upstream is set to remote branchA”. In your new question I hope you will explain that.

Comment: Sorry, don't know git very well. I read about tracking branch and upstream and they seem to be similar things. fixed my question. Thanks